# Confused with an SQL Query using UNIQUE

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

Let's assume we have the following relation model. 
The **primary keys** for each relation appear in **bold**:

**Sailors** (**sid**, name, rating, age)

**Boats** (**bid**, name, color)

**Reserve** (**sid, bid, day**)

I came up with the following query: " Find the sailor who has reserved boat 101 at **most once**. " The answer was given as follows:

```
SELECT S.sid
FROM Sailors S
WHERE UNIQUE (SELECT R.sid
              FROM Reserves R
              WHERE R.bid = '101' AND S.sid = R.sid)
```

What I don't get is how this query returns the sailors that haven't reserved this boat. I get that the nested query returns all the sids from Sailors who have reserved at least one time the boat with bid = 101.

Then by using the "UNIQUE" clause we demand the sids to be unique, so we remove duplicates and hold the sids from Sailors that have reserved boat with bid = 101 once.

However, do we get somehow the sailors that have never reserved boat 101? If no, then we don't actually calculate the sailors who have reserved boat 101 at most once but the sailors who have reserved boat 101 **exactly once**.

Am I correct or do I miss something?

Comment: Where unique is not valid mysql as far as I know where did you get this from?

Comment: @P.Salmon Is this valid with postgresql so that I update tags? It's more like a theoritical question on sql. Didn't try to run it.

Comment: I don't know but I have never come across unique being used in any context on any of the sqls I do know other than for qualifying indexes.

Comment: I disagree with your thinking. The sub query would return sailors who have hired a boat one or more times. Even if you de-duped that would still be true.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the UNIQUE syntax, but to get the result you could simply use:

```
SELECT R.sid FROM Reserves R where R.did=101 GROUP BY R.sid HAVING count(*)=1
```